# How can I use the ReverseString function in Delphi2009?

Tags: delphi, string, reverse

How can I use the `ReverseString` function in Delphi2009?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know anything about Delphi, but a [simple google search for "ReverseString Delphi 2009"](http://www.google.com/search?q=ReverseString+Delphi+2009) would have led you to this answer:

```
var s : string;

s:='ABOUT DELPHI PROGRAMMING';
s:=ReverseString(s);

//s='GNIMMARGORP IHPLED TUOBA'
// this code is from about.com
```

So, I'm assuming you're encountering other problems?

Comment: He may mean "what's the bloody point of it?" other than stupid palindromic games or checking that your password isn't just your username backwards? :-) Still, +1, since that's probably how you *do* use it.

Comment: To pass a job interview at Fog Creek? :)

Comment: At Fog Creek he would have to write it in C, otherwise Joel would not hire him, ever.

Comment: in "my" version of delphi 2009 at unit sysUtils, there is no ReverseString function.

Answer (score 0):

@Pax - I'm using it for a teleprompter program for a friend.  Not sure what other uses there are, but that's the one I've found for it.  I was elated to find a built-in function so I didn't have to do it myself... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for that on my ZX Spectrum ages ago to find words that rhymes.
Reversing words and then sorting them will give decent results, at least in Swedish.